# Get list of directories mid chef run

Tags: chef-infra

I am using Chef to manage Ubuntu servers. I am adding a console toolkit to every user that is present on the servers, most of which are created during the first Chef run. When running Chef for the first time, the users are created, but this block of code does not add the symlink to the toolkit, or create the proper .bashrc file. I think this is because the ruby `Dir.open('/home')` is being compiled at the start of the run before the users are created, because the files are added correctly on the next Chef run.

How would I get the list of directories to reflect the current state of the system when this recipe is actually run? I think a `ruby_block` might be what I need to look at, but I am unsure on how to apply it here.

```
# Loop over all user folders
Dir.open('/home').each do |user_dir|
  next if user_dir.start_with?('.')

  link "/home/#{user_dir}/.bash_it" do
    to '/home/.bash_it/'
    link_type :symbolic
  end

  template "/home/#{user_dir}/.bashrc" do
    source 'bashrc.erb'
    owner user_dir
    group user_dir
    mode '0644'
  end
end
```

Comment: could you do something like add it to /etc/skel on the box so that it created automatically as part of adding a user?

Comment: A ruby_block may be the solution yes, a definition or a provider too as it will be compiled when called at converge time (and so your dirs would have been already created). doing it in a two pass way (two chef run) is another way to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you create these template and link in the same place (inside the loop) where you create users or using the exact the same loop here (I mean going through the users that you have installed by chef and not through existing users)? That would be a better solution to my mind.

But if you still want to use it like that you have to use ruby_block and declare template and link dynamically

```
ruby_block 'Creating link and template' do
  block do
    Dir.open('/home').each do |user_dir|
      next if user_dir.start_with?('.')

      link = Chef::Resource::Link.new "/home/#{user_dir}/.bash_it", run_context
      link.to '/home/.bash_it/'
      link.link_type :symbolic
      link.run_action :create

      tplt = Chef::Resource::Template.new "/home/#{user_dir}/.bashrc", run_context
      tplt.source 'bashrc.erb'
      tplt.owner user_dir
      tplt.group user_dir
      tplt.mode '0644'
      tplt.run_action :create
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I am using the chef user lwrp to add users from data bags, so there is no loop I can get ahold of to process this in. I have been playing with some different ways to attack this, but haven't had any luck. Since this isn't anything critical, I think I will just live with it taking 2 runs to get everything setup.

Comment: The Chef Resource Link is now `Chef::Resource::Link.new` not `Chef::Resource.Link.new` - learned the hard way. ;)